# how can i compare the index in iPhone

Tags: iphone

i have taken indexes of an array which are shown in a tableview and i want to play at `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` which is same in index.

```
 MPMediaItem *item = [arrAnand objectAtIndex:3];
 NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
 AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
 player2 = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
 [player2 play];
```

here i have pass 3 ..but i need the index which is match to select at did select row

help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexpath:` pass an IndexPath object, which contains the index of the selected table cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  MPMediaItem *item = [arrAnand objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
  AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
  player2 = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
  [player2 play];
}
```

The `indexPath.row` will give you the direct index if you do not have any sections in your tableView.